# Collect without grouping terms

Tags: simplifying-expressions, formatting, algebraic-manipulation

The built-in function `Collect`, when applied to more than one variable, will group expressions by the first variable, as here:

```
 testexpr=1 + 2 x y^3 + a y^4 + b y^4 + y^5 + 2 a x^2 y z - 2 b x^2     
 y z +  a^2 x y^2 z - b^2 x y^2 z + a x y^3 z - b x y^3 z;
 Collect[testexpr,{x,y,z},f]
```

this gives

```
 f[1] + y^5 f[1] + x^2 y z f[2 a - 2 b] + y^4 f[a + b] + 
 x (y^3 (f[2] + z f[a - b]) + y^2 z f[a^2 - b^2])
```

But in my experience it is often more useful not to do this grouping, i.e. to expand the bracket after x, to get the result

```
f[1] + y^5 f[1] + x y^3 f[2] + x^2 y z f[2 a - 2 b] + 
x y^3 z f[a - b] + y^4 f[a + b] + x y^2 z f[a^2 - b^2]
```

One example that i have now is that the `x,y,z` are complicated expressions of a variable and the arguments of `f` are polynomials in this variable, and i want to integrate each term separately (as Mathematica has trouble with the full thing, but not the parts), so I really need to have each term separate.

This is one example, but I ran into this problem multiple times. As far as I'm aware there's no standard way to do this, so I've tried writing my own, which is this:

```
myExpand[expr_] := Replace[expr, 
HoldPattern[a_ (x : Plus[_ ..])] :>(a*# & /@ x) , {0,1}]
myCollect[expr_, vars_, funct_ : (#1 #2&)] := 
FixedPoint[myExpand, Collect[expr, vars, fDummy]] //.
{a_ fDummy[x_] :> fDummy[a, x], a_ fDummy[b_, x_] :> fDummy[a b, x]} /. 
fDummy[x_] :> fDummy[1, x] /. fDummy -> funct
```

Here `myExpand` expands terms at the first level, and it is applied with `FixedPoint` to deal with nested brackets. Then the replacement wraps the variables and the coefficient of each term with a dummy function `fDummy`, the next replacement adds a 1 as the first argument to the term with no variables and the last replacement applies the function `funct`.

It will give

```
myCollect[testexpr, {x, y, z}, f]
f[1, 1] + f[x y^3, 2] + f[y^4, a + b] + f[y^5, 1] + 
f[x^2 y z, 2 a - 2 b] + f[x y^2 z, a^2 - b^2] + f[x y^3 z, a - b]
```

Perhaps it's also useful to have something slightly more general, where each variable is a different argument (as in `f[x,y^3,z,a-b]` instead of `f[x y^3 z,a-b]`), but for my purposes this was enough.

I think this works fine, but I was wondering if anyone has a simpler and/or faster solution.

Comment: Why can't we just apply `Expand` to the expression after collecting? Perhaps it's not general enough, but `Expand@Collect[testexpr, {x,y,z}, f] /. a_ f[x_] :> f[a, x]` works for your example.

Comment: What i want is to expand the expression in powers of the given variables, but not expand each of those terms themselves, which is what your code does. For example to pick certain elements in an expression which you know are not going to simplify with each other, expand in those and simplify their coefficients.

Comment: I see! I will think on this then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

The `CoefficientRules` method given below won't work if one wants to collect by patterns like `Log[_]` or `_Log` (although it will work if the stuff inside the `Log` is explicitly given). In this case, my instinct is that `Collect` is then the way to go, and the method supplied by the OP will work pretty well as it is.

---

### `CoefficientRules` method

**Variables together**

```
poly = 1 + 2 x y^3 + a y^4 + b y^4 + y^5 + 2 a x^2 y z 
         - 2 b x^2 y z + a^2 x y^2 z - b^2 x y^2 z + a x y^3 z - b x y^3 z;

Total@KeyValueMap[
  f[Times @@ ({x, y, z}^#1), #2] &, Association@CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}]
 ]
```

> ```
> f[1, 1] + f[x y^3, 2] + f[y^4, a + b] + f[y^5, 1] 
>         + f[x^2 y z, 2 a - 2 b] + f[x y^2 z, a^2 - b^2] + f[x y^3 z, a - b]
> ```

**Variables apart**

```
Total@KeyValueMap[
  f[Sequence @@ ({x, y, z}^#1), #2] &, Association@CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}]
 ]
```

> ```
> f[1, 1, 1, 1] + f[1, y^4, 1, a + b] + f[1, y^5, 1, 1] + f[x, y^2, z, a^2 - b^2] 
>               + f[x, y^3, 1, 2] + f[x, y^3, z, a - b] + f[x^2, y, z, 2 a - 2 b]
> ```

---

**Non-Association alternative**

I realized that there is a cleaner version using `@@@` (although a little slower for some reason):

```
Total[f[Sequence @@ ({x, y, z}^#1), #2] & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}]]
```

Replace `Sequence` with `Times` for the "Variables together" form.

Comment: That looks interesting, I have to look at it as I'm not familiar with Association.

Comment: @Jansen, `Association` was introduced in v10, so you won't have it if you are using an earlier version.

Comment: No I have the latest version, I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I was looking for, there is one problem though. I didn't emphasise it in my question, but i want to be able to collect also compound expressions and patterns, like you can with `Collect`, for example `{Log[_],ArcTanh[_]}`. This doesn't work with `CoefficientRules`.

Comment: @Jansen, you are right (but although `CoefficientRules` doesn't work for patterns it will work for more complicated terms, if the whole term is explicitly specified). Given this, I suspect `Collect` is the way to go and the answer you give in your question is as efficient as anything. If I think of something, I'll add it.