# How to organize expression by symbols (like Collect), but apply different functions to each coefficient

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, functional-style

I want to mimic the functionality of `Collect[expr, {vars}, func]`, but with the following modification:  The function `f` that is applied to each coefficient is different, and depends on which variable it is a coefficient of.  The `vars` are expressions of predetermined known heads (which in the example below are `_e`, `_f`, `_g`, `_h`).

Example:

```
expr = -2 x e[x] + x e[y] + x^2 e[x] + y e[x] + y e[y] + x^2 f[x] + y^2 f[x] + x^2 g[x] + y^2 h[x]
```

1. I need to collect `expr` by `e[_]`, `f[_]`, `g[_]` and `h[_]`.
2. Apply `simpE` to the coefficients of `e[_]`, and `simpF` to the coefficients of `f[_]`, and `simpGen` to the coefficient of everything else.
3. This needs to work even when certain terms are absent from `expr`.  *e.g.* if `expr` doesn't have any `e[_]`  *etc.*

My idea (which doesn't work) is to do this in two steps:

1. First collect the expression:

   ```
   Collect[expr, {_f, _e, _g, _h}]
   ```
2. Then replace with the rule that makes the transformation on each coefficient.

   ```
   rule = (Plus[
      Optional[Times[exprE_., funcE_e]], 
      Optional[Times[exprF_., funcF_f]], 
      rest_.]) :> 
   (simpE[exprE] funcE + simpF[exprF] funcF + Collect[rest,{_g, _h}, simpRest])
   ```

The (not quite correct) result is:

```
Collect[expr, {_f, _e, _g, _h}] /. rule
```

> e[x] simpE[-2 x + x^2 + y] + f[x] simpF[x^2 + y^2] + 
>    g[x] simpRest[x^2] + h[x] simpRest[y^2] + simpRest[(x + y) e[y]]

But this doesn't work because

1. the `rule` groups `e[y]` with the rest of the terms and incorrectly applies `simpRest` to it (see last term of output), instead of `simpE[x+y] e[y]`.
2. If certain terms are absent, then the `rule` doesn't even match.  Consider `expr2` below which is absent of `f[_]`:

   ```
   expr2 = -2 x e[x] + x^2 e[x] + y e[x] + x e[y] + y e[y] + x^2 g[x] + y^2 h[x]
   ```

   The rule doesn't match:

   ```
   Collect[expr, {_f, _e, _g, _h}] /. rule
   ```

   > (-2 x + x^2 + y) e[x] + (x + y) e[y] + x^2 g[x] + y^2 h[x]

I need help with this particular modification of `Collect`.  Is there a *sexy* way to get this done?

Comment: Perhaps the function `myCollect` in this thread http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85479/collect-without-grouping-terms could help. It modifies collect to use a function not just of the coefficient but also of the term itself. You could then just use an if statement in the function you apply to differentiate the different terms. Don't know how sexy this is though.

Comment: I notice that you have not Accepted an answer.  Do neither of the answers work as you would like?  Could you include the exact output that you hope for from each example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ive been traveling, then got sick... Will come back when I get better

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you have been ill.  I hope it is entirely temporary and you are well very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following.  Simplifying a left-over constant term along with the other coefficients seems hard to comprise in a single, simple function.

```
forms = {_f, _e, _g, _h};
funcs = {simpF, simpE, simpG, simpH};
simpConstant[c_] := simpC[c];
Times[c_simpAll, form_] ^:= (c /. simpAll -> (form /. Thread[forms -> funcs])) form;

Collect[2 + expr, {_f, _e, _g, _h}, simpAll] /. simpAll -> simpConstant
Collect[2 + expr2, {_f, _e, _g, _h}, simpAll] /. simpAll -> simpConstant
Collect[2 + x, {_f, _e, _g, _h}, simpAll] /. simpAll -> simpConstant
(*
  simpC[2] + e[y] simpE[x + y] + e[x] simpE[-2 x + x^2 + y] + 
   f[x] simpF[x^2 + y^2] + g[x] simpG[x^2] + h[x] simpH[y^2]

  simpC[2] + e[y] simpE[x + y] + e[x] simpE[-2 x + x^2 + y] + 
   g[x] simpG[x^2] + h[x] simpH[y^2]

  simpC[2 + x]
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
funs = {f, e, g, h}
apply = {sf, se, sgen, sgen}
k[a_, b_] := (Head@b /. Thread[funs -> apply])[a] b

Collect[z@x expr, Blank/@funs] /. (Times[a___, l: Blank@#, r___] :> k[a r, l] &/@funs)
(*

e[y] se[(x + y) z[x]] +
e[x] se[(-2 x + x^2 + y) z[x]] + 
f[x] sf[(x^2 + y^2) z[x]] +
g[x] sgen[x^2 z[x]] + 
h[x] sgen[y^2 z[x]]
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this. First you modify collect so that it doesn't group terms, and so the function acts not only on the coefficient but also on the variable, like so

```
myCollect[expr_, vars_, funct_ : (#1 #2 &)] := 
 Expand@Collect[expr, vars, fDummy] //. {a_ fDummy[x_] :> 
  fDummy[a, x], a_ fDummy[b_, x_] :> fDummy[a b, x]} /. 
  fDummy[x_] :> fDummy[1, x] /. fDummy -> funct
```

Then simply define

```
simp[arg_e, coeff_] := arg simpE[coeff]
simp[arg_f, coeff_] := arg simpF[coeff]
simp[arg_, coeff_] := arg simpGen[coeff]
```

and apply:

```
myCollect[expr, {_f, _e, _g, _h}, simp]
(* e[y] simpE[x + y] + e[x] simpE[-2 x + x^2 + y] + 
f[x] simpF[x^2 + y^2] + g[x] simpGen[x^2] + h[x] simpGen[y^2] *)
```

or for the second case,

```
myCollect[expr2, {_f, _e, _g, _h}, simp]
(* e[y] simpE[x + y] + e[x] simpE[-2 x + x^2 + y] + g[x] simpGen[x^2] + 
 h[x] simpGen[y^2] *)
```